# JxPath: evaluation of '' = 0

Tags: java, xpath, expression, equality, jxpath

I am evaluating the expression `'' = 0` in JxPath 1.3, and I expect the result to be false. This is my code:

```
JXPathContext.newContext(ctaSectionABean).getValue("'' = 0");
```

However, the result returned to be is true! If I evaluate the same expression in Eclipse jxpath tool I get false, which I expect to be correct, since the [documentation of xpath1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Expressions) section 3.4 says the following:

> When neither object to be compared is a node-set and the operator is =
>   or !=, then the objects are compared by converting them to a common
>   type as follows and then comparing them. If at least one object to be
>   compared is a boolean, then each object to be compared is converted to
>   a boolean as if by applying the boolean function. Otherwise, if at
>   least one object to be compared is a number, then each object to be
>   compared is converted to a number as if by applying the number
>   function. Otherwise, both objects to be compared are converted to
>   strings as if by applying the string function. The = comparison will
>   be true if and only if the objects are equal; the != comparison will
>   be true if and only if the objects are not equal. Numbers are compared
>   for equality according to IEEE 754 [IEEE 754]. Two booleans are equal
>   if either both are true or both are false. Two strings are equal if
>   and only if they consist of the same sequence of UCS characters.

So, since no object is a boolean and one of them is a number, I expect JxPath to try and convert them both to numbers. That would be `0` for `0` and `NaN` for `''`, and I tested that JxPath does convert them that way with the `number()` function. That means that JxPath does not try to convert them to numbers, as the spec defines.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Does `'' = NaN` work? (Not super familiar with the finer points of xpath, but seems that NaN ≠ 0?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if your information is correct then I think this is a bug.

Comment: I have posted the exact same question in the mailing list: http://markmail.org/search/?q=fragkakis%20list%3Aorg.apache.commons.users%2F#query:fragkakis%20list%3Aorg.apache.commons.user+page:1+mid:xdvqw254uknpuadu+state:results